# How to compute orthonormal polynomials from weight function?

Tags: numerical-methods, orthogonal-polynomials

I have a weight function $w(x)=e^{-x}$ with $x$ from $0$ (inclusive) to infinity. How would I compute the first four orthonormal polynomials with respect to this weight function?

Comment: Just use Gram–Schmidt on $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Gram-Schnidt process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to the set of polynomials

> $$\left\{ 1,x,x^2, x^3\right\} $$

using the inner product

> $$ <f,g> = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)g(x) e^{-x}dx . $$

Here is the first two $\left\{ 1,(x-1)\right\}$.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [table of orthogonal polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthogonalPolynomials.html), these are [Laguerre Polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials): they are solution to  Laguerre's Differential Equation and can be also found using $L_n(x)=\frac{1}{n!} \left( \frac{d}{dx} -1 \right) ^n x^n$. Here are the first four: $\left\{1,\; -x+1,\; \frac{1}{2}(x^2-4x+2),\; \frac{1}{6}(-x^3+9x^2-18x+6)\right\}$.

$$$$